# Redirecting /page/*/ to the home page in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url, duplicate-content, canonical-url

My problem is that my homepage exists on `https://www.example.com/page/2/`, `/3/`, `/4/` and so on, it still exists on `/1000/`. Same duplicate page versions exists on `/about` and and `/contact` page of my site.

Now what I want is to redirect all the `https://www.example.com/page/*` URLs to `https://www.example.com`

What code should I use on *.htaccess* to fix these duplicate page versions of my website?

Comment: Unless something is linking to those page numbers, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: To clarify, `https://www.example.com/` does currently display your homepage and this is the URL that you are linking to throughout your site?

Answer (score 2):

rule for all after `/page/*` redirecting to homepage:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page\/(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
```

or all `/page/0-9+/` redirecting to homepage:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page\/(\d+)\/$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: No need to escape the slash in Apache regex (since there is no slash delimiter, the slash has no special meaning).